# cant compile audio software

Tags: sound, compiling, alsa, jack

I tried to install an audio software (SO-KL5 synth). My distro is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I try to compile the software, it says it cant find jack and ALSA header files.

Where are these files?

### Edit 1:

I can't install `libjack-dev`, my terminal says:

```
Unable to install some packages . This may be because you
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the distribution
"Unstable" and some required packages have not yet been created or
There have not yet entered from " Incoming ".
The following information may help to resolve the situation :

The following packages have unmet dependencies :
 libjack -dev : Depends : libjack0 ( = 1: 0.121.3 + 20120418git75e3e20b - 2.1ubuntu1 ) but will not be installed
E: Unable to correct problems , you have held packages are broken .
```

### Edit 2:

I could finally fix this error reinstalling libjack0, apparently it had an error.

Answer (score 3):

The jack and ALSA header files should be provided by packages `libjack-dev` and `libasound2-dev` respectively.